# Horizontal Frequency Out of Range

Tags: ubuntu, display

I've been running Ubuntu on one of my servers for about six months. Recently, every time I turn on the computer it POSTs and then right before it gets into Ubuntu my monitor gives me an error saying:

```
Out of Range
H: 92 kHz
V: 58 kHz
Range:
H: 22-82 kHz
V: 56-76 Hz
Max: 1280 x 1024
```

Obviously the horizontal frequency is at 92 kHz, which is apparently out of its range. It's an older (~2005) LiquidVideo 17" flat screen monitor with the old blue VGA input. I have access to the BIOS but that doesn't really help. If I had another monitor I would hook it up to that to troubleshoot and figure out whether it's the monitor or the graphics card or what. Even if I am able to get into the desktop I don't think there's a setting for horizontal frequency, only vertical. How do I fix this?

Here's a picture:

[image: horz out of range]

Comment: believe this is a too high resolution problem. while that means it is a frequency required to get to that resolution, trying to address the frequency itself would be overthinking it. lower the res and refresh rate, however that is accomplished

Comment: broken link. in addition, can you boot the system and plug in the screen after it boots to some extent?

Comment: Picture is fixed. And yes, I can boot the system and get into the BIOS, and I've also successfully booted into a Live CD, however I don't see how I can change things on the main Ubuntu installation from the Live CD.

Answer (score 3):

Try to attach better monitor, maybe that alone will solve the problem. Otherwise you can boot with bootable CD that work and edit Xorg.conf file.

Comment: I have a bootable USB stick however I didn't think I could edit files on my main Ubuntu installation from the live disk. What specifically should I be editing in Xorg.conf?

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl-Alt-F1
Login to the non-graphical interface
Fix the resolution in the xwindows start up config file
  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Resolution

reboot

Comment: Instead of posting links to references, please reproduce/quote the relevant information here. Sometimes resources move or are removed, which would make your answer no longer useful, therefore you should always include all pertinent information in the answer rather than referring to another source.

Comment: It is not necessary to reboot to have the new X config take effect. Just restart the X server, which you can usually do by pressing control+alt+backspace in the X session.